# Harmon.ie add in for outlook web client does not drag/drop attachments

Tags: outlook, harmon.ie

I am using harmon.ie add in in Outlook desktop and web client. This is configured to work with SharePoint 2013 On-Premises. The add-in lets me drag/drop email attachments in Outlook desktop client but does not let me drag/drop attachments in Outlook web client.

Outlook 2016 CU6 IE11

Cheers,
A

Answer (score 0):

Harmon.ie App does not currently allow/work D&D.